# In MySQL, Is it possible to set dates as column name

Tags: mysql, date

In MySQL, Is it possible to set dates as column name.
I am thinking about to create a table with last 3 week data where column names of all three weeks will be the first date of that week.
So if currante date is 25-09-2013 then my table should have 3 columns with column name as:
11-09-2013,28-09-2013 and 25-09-2013.

Comment: It would help us visualize the situation better, if you also explain why you would want to do that.

Comment: Please explain the _problem you are trying to solve_, not ask for help with the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, why not:

```
mysql> select 'foo' as `2013-09-25`;
+------------+
| 2013-09-25 |
+------------+
| foo        |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

-just remember about backticks.

But, actually, if you want to produce some dynamic columns that is not a good idea - you'd better to use application for that.

Answer (score 1):

It might be *possible*, but I'd say it's a terrible, denormalized, unsustainable, brain dead design.  I'd recommend rethinking it, knowing nothing about your requirements.

Comment: Yeh already my query is getting bigger. My table has 3 columns date, admin, msu and i am comparing msu of last 3 weeks. choosing them as 
Select ADMIN1,WEEK1,WEEK2,WEEK3,(((WEEK3-WEEK2)/WEEK2)*100) as percentage_change, (WEEK3-WEEK2) as MSU_Difference from .... All i wanted to print date in place of WEEK1, WEEK2, WEEK3.

Comment: You can easily do this with a one-to-many relationship: a foreign key between two tables and a JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

What is your justification for doing this?

If it is just so that the data looks more readable then that can be achieved by running a report that formats the data into the layout that you require.

Just store your data with a date tag on each entry, then retrieve it in 3 week blocks within your report.

Creating tables on the fly will add unnecessary overheads to your processing and complicate backup, replication and retrieval by other processes.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do that in the display layer.

select columns as

```
if(date=curdate() - interval 1 day, result, null) as today_minus_1,
if(date=curdate() - interval 2 day, result, null) as today_minus_2,
if(date=curdate() - interval 2 day, result, null) as today_minus_3,
```

afterwards when you are displaying, rename them. I did something like that before to compare performance of campaigns, but column naming as date was done when creating the data table.